# Changing navbar-inner color in media query of twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries, navbar

In normal web browser looks like following[image]

I have overwritten the bootstrap's following rules in a different file code is given bellow

```
  body {
        margin-left: 8px;
        margin-right:8px;

    }

    div .span8 {
        border: 2px solid rgb(121, 25, 77);
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px;
        background-color: rgb(188, 187, 178);
    }

    div .span2 {
        border: 2px solid rgb(163, 43, 70);
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px;
        background-color: rgb(240, 225, 200);
    }
    .navbar-inner {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #04998D, #f2f2f2);
    }

    .navbar .nav > li > a {
        color: #D33333;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #19B95F;
    }

    .navbar .nav li.dropdown.open > 
    .dropdown-toggle, .navbar .nav li.dropdown.active > 
    .dropdown-toggle, .navbar .nav li.dropdown.open.active > 
    .dropdown-toggle {
         color: #555555;
         background-color: #83C0AF;
      }

      .dropdown-menu {
          background-color: #64bead;
          background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #04998D, #f2f2f2);
      }
```

My problem is when I browse it from any mobile device, I see no change in navbar-inner. Others are changed. I know that, I have to change in bootstrap-responsive.css file. But I have no idea how I will change it.

I want my nabar like following in mobile.

[image]

But navbar color is white as was before.

So, How can I change in media query.

Comment: Instead of changing bootstrap.css, you can create embedded style sheet with these styles so that this would override bootstrap.css in any screen..

Comment: Can you see other changes on your site? If not it's time to check your caching :) By the way... Editing the original bootstrap.css isn't the best solution. So you are not able to upgrade to a newer bootstrap version :/

Comment: Yes .... Others are ok. Only navbar is unchanged.

Comment: Did you only change one background-image? I think you have die edit each background-image property. Look at http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient :)

Comment: Yes ... I changed one background-image only.

Comment: TIP: never try to re-structure frameworks! rather overwrite the rules you want to alter in a different file.

Comment: Ok I have overwritten the rules in a different file. Please have a look to it.

Comment: If you are only use `linear-gradient` it will only work in new browsers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient part Browser compatibility. You have to add all other background-image gradients too

Comment: "All other backround-image" means what?

Comment: That means you need background-image properties with `-webkit-gradient`, `-webkit-linear-gradient`, `-moz-linear-gradient` and `linear-gradient`. Look at yout bootstrap css code and copy all background-image lines and custimze them.

Answer (score 1):

For customizing bootstrap refer to [Customizing Bootstrap documentation.](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#customizing) Look at Customizing components sub section.
So in you case you should override .navbar-inner in css which is loaded after bootstrap.css.

To change color scheme you could also:

- use [customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)
- download less source and modify variables.

By doing so you change color at all places, so you dont have to search for specific color through entire css and replace it with new one.

Comment: I need not to customize it. Now I want to overwrite it for all device.

Comment: Try to add your custom .navbar-inner class after bootstrap.css. Either in separate file or append it to the end of bootstrap.css. This way it should have priority.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion with  [Sentencio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1788002/sentencio), I found my mistake. Now I am going to tell how I solved it.

I changed the all background-image properties with -webkit-gradient, -webkit-linear-gradient, -moz-linear-gradient and linear-gradient. Code given bellow

```
.navbar-inner {
  min-height: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #04998D, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#04998D), to(#f2f2f2));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #04998D, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #04998D, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #04998D, #f2f2f2);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff2f2f2', GradientType=0);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
}
```